# Trying to increment an integer on click of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, scope, increment

I'm having a scope problem (I think) trying to increment an integer.

I have several CheckBoxes, and want to limit users to only choose a maximum of three. So, I want to increment an integer on each checkbox click which I can check against.

My Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" autopostback="true" OnCheckedChanged="MyCheckBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

My Default.aspx.cs

```
       public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(MapPath("App_Data/publications.xml"));
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }

        private static int mycount = 0;

        protected void MyCheckBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
                Label1.Text = mycount.ToString();
                Increment(mycount);
        }

        public static void Increment(int mycount) 
        { 
            mycount++; 
        }
}
```

My Label1 is always displaying 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names overlap inside the method scope of Increment. Remove mycount as parameter in Increment method